# Do right-handed helices bind to right-handed helices, and vice versa?

Tags: molecular-biology, protein-structure, organic-chemistry, nucleic-acids, structure-prediction

I know that B-conformation DNA is a right-handed helix, and most proteins that form helices form right-handed, not left-handed, helices (1). Furthermore, "Many transcription factors have an alpha-helix that binds to DNA bases in a specific fashion" (2), indicating that it is common for right-handed protein helices to bind to right-handed B-DNA helices.

Does this mean that, generally speaking, from the perspective of basic geometry, do right-handed helices bind to right- (but not left-)handed helices? And, vice versa, that left-handed helices generally bind to left- (but not right-)handed helices?

References

1. Novotny, M., & Kleywegt, G. J. (2005). A Survey of Left-handed Helices in Protein Structures. Journal of Molecular Biology, 347(2), 231–241. https://doi.org/10.1016/J.JMB.2005.01.037
2. Suzuki, M., & Gerstein, M. (1995). Binding geometry of alpha-helices that recognize DNA. Proteins, 23(4), 525–535. https://doi.org/10.1002/PROT.340230407

Comment: But the paper you quote shows that left-handed helices in proteins only span a single turn, so fair comparison with right-handed helices is not possible. The question seems to be a case of “if left-handed helices existed”, in which case it would seem a mathematical question.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that protein and DNA helices show the handedness that they do due largely to the [intrinsic chirality of their components](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32969653/). Note that in [natural biomolecules L-amino acids and D-sugars predominate](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1802647/). This apparently leads to a subsequent bias in their respective polymers.

I believe that it has been demonstrated that [artificial alpha helices constructed of achiral amino acids demonstrate inversions between left and right handed forms](https://www.asiaresearchnews.com/content/researchers-fix-chirality-helical-proteins)- these then need to be stapled with extra molecular bridges to hold left or right handed orientation.

Thus, I don't think that there is a right-to-right or left-to-left association. **In all cases, I think it's just that the biased handedness is baked into the structure of natural amino acids.**

Comment: Thanks, @Maximilian Press. What you're saying is true, but that's not really my question. I am NOT asking whether nuceic acids and proteins usually adopt right-handed helices because this makes it easier for them to bind to each other (nor am I suggesting this). I am simply asking, do right-handed helices bind more easily with other right-handed helices, and do left-handed helices tend to bind more readily and tightly with other left-handed helices? I'm being a bit coy because I don't want to give away my hypothesis, but I'm more interested in the LEFT-handed nucleic acid and protein helices.

Comment: @OdinTheDO I see. I would be interested in whether anyone had any data either way, but my guess on this is a solid "no". I think that the secondary structure of helical geometry of DNA and protein with respect to each other is probably low/no relevance for binding compared to the tertiary and quaternary structures. But that's purely a guess.